# Insert values at cursor pointer and how to assign to ng-model - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to insert values at cursor pointer but unable to assign the textarea value to ng-model.

```js
app.directive('myText', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.$on('add', function(e, val) {
        var domElement = element[0];

        if (document.selection) {
          domElement.focus();
          var sel = document.selection.createRange();
          sel.text = val;
          domElement.focus();
        } else if (domElement.selectionStart || domElement.selectionStart === 0) {
          var startPos = domElement.selectionStart;
          var endPos = domElement.selectionEnd;
          var scrollTop = domElement.scrollTop;
          domElement.value = domElement.value.substring(0, startPos) + val + domElement.value.substring(endPos, domElement.value.length);
          domElement.focus();
          domElement.selectionStart = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.selectionEnd = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
          domElement.value += val;
          domElement.focus();
        }

      });
    }
  }
}]);

$scope.insertValue = function(value, type) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('add', value);
  //$scope.model.userApprovalMessage = $scope.model.userApprovalMessage + "   " + value; 
  $scope.model.userApprovalMsgLength = 300 - parseFloat($scope.model.userApprovalMessage.length);

};
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ng-class="model.webPageSkin3">Insert Tag</button>
  <ul class="action-dropdown dropdown-menu ">
    <li ng-click="insertValue('$Name')"><a>$Name</a></li>
    <li ng-click="insertValue('$Groupz')"><a>$Groupz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <br>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <textarea class="compose-msg-area form-control compose-textarea" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; white-space: pre-wrap; margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="model.userApprovalMessage" placeholder="Text Message" maxlength="300" ng-change="userApprovalMessageLength(model.userApprovalMessage)"
    my-text="">
                            </textarea>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" numbers-only disabled style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width: 40px; background-color: #fff; padding: 5px; height: 30px; margin-top: -20px; font-weight: 600; margin-left: 5px;" ng-model="model.userApprovalMsgLength">
    <label class="pull-right text-left1" for="street">text left</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to display the `$scope.model.userApprovalMessage` length. When I try to insert $Name at cursor pointer. I am able to add but the model value is not changing.

Comment: I'd suggest you make a pen or fiddle. Would go a long way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/lFZugW6xX5CqbxyWuqYS?p=preview

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do. correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to insert the message length on click and then add that value to the end of the element/string of where you last clicked?

Comment: I selected somewhere or middle of text in the textarea. When I click on insert tag button and select any option from the dropdown that value I need to insert in the selected space inside textarea and need to send to backend. So i am using ng-model name. But for me values getting inserted but unable to assign that particular textarea value to a ng-model name.